# How do you display:none to links or h2s containing a certain string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm going to give this question another shot. Thanks to everyone who provided advice in asking questions.

Here is a my JSfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/trevhud/VFJf8/4/

And a sample of the html:

```
<div class= "category-tree">
<section class="category mainCat">
    <h2><a href="#">Documentation</a></h2>
</section>
<section class="category">
    <h2><a href="#">General</a></h2>
    <section class="section">
        <h3><a href="#">General</a></h3>
        <ul class="article-list">
            <li><a href="#">Reset or Reactivate</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Create an account</a></li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</section
</div>
```

As you can see, when you click a category, the sections pop down. When you click a section, the article list pops down.

When the h2 under category has the same exact text as the h3 under section, I would like to hide the h3 and immediately show the article list. This is so the user doesn't have the redundancy of having to click twice to see the article list on links that say the exact same thing. I've included a potential answer at the bottom of my JS, which seems to be not exactly what I am describing. Thanks to everyone for the help

Comment: You generally want to boil your questions down to the simplest possible reproduction of your error or difficulty rather than simply copying and pasting your code.  What you have here is somewhat difficult for someone looking at if for the first time to glance over.

Comment: Agreed. You just need a tiny tiny jsFiddle with only the basic code to recreate the context.

Comment: You aren't going to want to do this by string I think. I bet data-attributes are going to be great here, but we'll need something more to work with than this code. This code isn't even formatted in a readable manner, and there are selectors in your CSS that aren't in your HTML, and `.category-tree` isn't in your HTML + your hrefs are of no importance.

Comment: here is a jsFiddle for you to use as a cleaner starting point: http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/cJupw/

Comment: Thanks for the tips and the jsfiddle sheriffderek. I've included a bit more than I need I suppose, mainly because I want to make sure the solution does not involve hiding or breaking the functionality of any other areas. I'd be happy to continue to edit and simplify as needed. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check the text of the h2 versus the next h3 tag you could do something like this in your click event:

```
if($(this).next().find('h3 a').text() == $(this).text()) 
{
    $(this).next().find('h3').toggle();
}
```

Comment: In looking at your fiddle, $(this) is referencing the "a" node. You also need to call the above inside the .on("click") event.  I've forked your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/brettwlutz/VFJf8/5/  Basically you have to look at the parent (h2 or h3), then find the next. i.e. $(this).parent().next().find('h3 a').text()